# python find tags in deep nodes xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to reach the "thirdDepth1" tag using python ElementTree library. Below is the simplified version. In my real xml its depth is dynamic. So can't reach it  with giving path, using find(),findall(), iterfind(). Any ideas?

```
<root>
    <firstDepth1>
        <secondDepth1>
            <thirdDepth1>thirdDepthVal</thirdDepth1>
        </secondDepth1>
    </firstDepth1>
    <firstDepth2>
        <secondDepth2></secondDepth2>
    </firstDepth2>
</root>
```

Comment: First, good questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Second, I suggest to use lxml which is better featured than ElementTree. Third, learn xpath basisc, yours could be a relative one `//thirdDepth1`.

Comment: With proper `xpath`, you can reach them.

Comment: Thank you problem solved, xpath as ".//thirdDepth1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("testxmlreqpython.xml")

root = tree.getroot()

element = root.find(".//thirdDepth1")

print(element)
```

From [@Luis Muñoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2834978/luis-mu%C3%B1oz) comment, this can be achived by using xpath as ".//thirdDepth1"